# SQL Server: is there a way to theoretically estimate retrieval time of a query

Tags: sql-server, data-retrieval, elapsedtime

i will be having a Database with more than 8 hundred billion records,

i am gonna be querying the DB via SQL Server **ONLY** to retrieve records i.e. **SELECT** queries only.

i am gonna be retrieving from 1 to 36,000,000 records, plus i will also think about caching (36,000,000 x 8 ) records.

what i was looking for is some means through which i could get an estimation of **HOW MUCH TIME** will it take for a simple **SELECT** query SQL Server (any version\edition) to get back 36,000,000(worst case scenario).

My table is simple with only 9 columns\attributes, all of them INT(integers).

I need to get an idea of this before hand before i could populate my DB & design my App while keeping in mind that whether i have to rely on SQL Server or my App has to rely on huge caching because slow response is **NOT** an option.

EXTRA NOTE

- Network Connection and bandwidth is not a consideration here.
- I cannot check elapsed time via programming, because DB is\can not
  populated yet.

---

**E D I T**

why the down vote

Comment: There are so many variables here it isn't funny. Nobody is going to be able to give you anything close to a guess without being able to populate your data, in your schema, on your hardware, using your queries and usage patterns. Sorry, no magic involved with extrapolation from number of rows to a reliable estimate of query time.

Comment: keeping alllllllllllll the variables aside, how about a worst case search through `Eight Hundred Billion Records`

Comment: Absolutely no idea, sorry. You can't "keep all the variables aside" - my eight hundred billion rows are going to look a lot different than yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Populate your table with junk data and turn on statistics.

Comment: anh... 36 million records will produce a Graphical Representation, of at max 3600 x 3600 pixels.

Comment: Gotcha.  You should probably include those details in the question next time so people have an understanding of what it is you're attempting to do.

Comment: dude, my question was not whether people will look at these many records or whatever, my concern was only return time.

Comment: dude, and I answered it in my first sentence.  I even revised my answer to make it more clear. But, if you include more detail people may suggest alternative solutions as well, possibly something you hadn't thought of. But if you're just looking for a true|false - well, you got it.

Comment: dude, okay, junk data it is then.. lemme try it... 12 Terabytes of Junk Data... got it.

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry, no easy silver bullet. You an deduct that from other queries if you have a sensible data reference set and can live with variations, but otherwise - no. People earn money tuning that ;)